# Fall-through if default is in middle of switch case?

Tags: java, switch-statement, default

I have a question. In a switch statement, is `default` tested for last even if it isn't last?

If so, in the following code snippet:

```
int i = 6;
int a=0, b=0, c=0;
switch (i) 
{
    case 1: 
    a++; 
    case 2: 
    default: 
    case 3: 
    b++; 
    case 6:
    c++; 
}
System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
```

After matching with case 6, and incrementing the value of c, since there is no break, will it go back to default?

I did try this code and it didn't seemly go to default and a fall-through did not occur. I just wanted to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`switch` is evaluated from matching `case` to either `break` or end of `switch` statement. If you pass 6 it will enter case for 6 and do only one increment. But if you enter 7 it will start from `default` and fall through to the end of switch doing two increments.

Answer (score 2):

There is no additional testing of case labels beyond the initial testing at the beginning of the switch statement.  Once `i` has been evaluated by the switch statement, control transfers to the `case 6:` label because that matches `i`.  Statements are then executed in order until the end of the switch statement, or until a `break` statement is encountered.  This means that only `c` is incremented.

A `break` statement will only end the execution of the entire switch statement; whether a `break` statement is present has no effect on retesting the switch expression, because retesting the switch expression will not occur either way.

If you want `default` to be the case label entered, then `i` must not match any case label at the *start* of the switch statement.  If `i` is `99` at the start of the switch statement, then both `b` and `c` are incremented (fallthrough occurs).

There is no restriction on where in the order of case labels a `default` label appears, only that at most one `default` occurs in a switch statement.

Comment: ...and that I suggest most people will do a double-take if default isn't last, so unusual is it to be found elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, all of your cases will fall through, as no case has a `break;` as well, your switch is conditionally based on `i`, so if you want to see each case, you need to change `i`.

Utilizing `break;` should not have any effect on where your cases reside in your switch state, this is also the "case" for `default`

Edit: As @Ivan mentioned, if fall through is intended, then the placement of your cases will matter